# Error linking a native library from another project to a JUnit Test Project

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-testing

I have run into some issues while working on Android JUnit Test, the details of which are given below.

I have an Android application (which is to be tested) and a corresponding JUnit Test project (which tests the application). Also, I have another project, which contains some native library which I intend to use in my Test project.

I have tried to use the other project as a library under eclipse but when running the JUnit test, an error comes up stating “findLibrary returned null”.

There is a workaround for this by putting the native library in the application to be tested and then using it. But I don’t want to put the testing library in the application. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Did you add the library to the java build path libraries under project properties?

Comment: I should have specifically asked if you added it under the project properties of the Test project.

Comment: Yes, I tried adding it to the project properties of the Test project. But no luck.